# Is Integrating an already existing php project with Laravel a wise choice?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-3

I have a website http://aw3some.tv/ , which was initially created to be just a simple video blog kind of a thing , and as such i didn't feel the need for any frameworks . I just divided my project in the following manner :

1) I created classes for doing specific jobs such as managing videos , handling database queries , storing the images to a cdn and so on . 
2) To separate the code and the html , i used Smarty Template Engine 
3) I use git to push my changes to the server .

However now i need the a host of other features to be implemented , and i've realized that a framework can come in handy now . So there are basically two ways to do this :
1) Code the entire website entirely from scratch using laravel
2) Leave the current part as it is , and add on to the features using laravel (All of this is to be done in the directory in which the project resides , without breaking the previous code).

Now , obviously option 1 will take a lot of time !! I was wondering whether option 2 is possible , and if possible is it recommended ?

Comment: i think you should incorporate you old code chunk by chunk into the new website(which will be beased on Laravel). This way you will only have to make structural changes and would be the fastest possible way.

Comment: First of all install a local working environment on your programming computer (this means install a web server nginx, apache2, etc with mysql). Copy your remote code to this working environment and create another virtual server and part by part write the code from scratch. Actually it takes far less than you think, I have migrated about 4 websites to Laravel in 6 months and it's worth the time you spare. You are already using templates and classes, so your time requirements would be much less than mine.